# ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED to load bootstarp CDN

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I have an Angular 6 application, where I'm using maxcdn 
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css 
This is an intranet application
The application works fine and loads bootstrap in US locations, but in one of the Asian countries, it gives error in Chrome dev tools:

`GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css` `net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED`

So question is what could cause for CDN not to be accessible?

Answer (score 0):

ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED may occur when Chrome is unable to render the proxy response for some sites.

Please refer following links: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/err-tunnel-connection-failed-error-chrome-solved/

May be solve your problem.